# Looping through InDesign file, placing graphic on each page

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe-indesign

I've set-up a document that contains identical structures, including a text box labeled "pageNumber" to hold a variable based on the page number, an empty rectangle to receive an illustrator file, and a text box filled with placeholder text.

Eventually, I'll be using data-merge to create a much longer document, comprised of identically structured pages, but containing personalized data.

(I created a zip file containing these elements, in case it would be helpful to see what I'm testing)( http://arthousemedia.com/files/PageNumbers.zip )

The jsx I've created works to an extent. When I run it, there are a couple alerts that show I've created the right variables) But instead of placing pageNumber-p1.ai on page one and pageNumber-p2 on the second page, whichever page I'm "focused" upon gets its graphic placed twice on page 1. Apparently, I'm not succeeding in looping through pages. Not sure.

Any advice you have would be helpful. Thanks.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument,
pagesLength = doc.pages.length; 

for (var i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++) {

    var myLabel = "pageNumber",
    myPage = app.properties.activeWindow && app.activeWindow.activePage,  
    myTextFrames = myPage.textFrames.everyItem().getElements(myLabel).slice(0),  
    l = myTextFrames.length,  
    myVariable

    alert(myVariable);

    while (l--) {  
        if (myTextFrames[l].label != myLabel) continue;  
        myVariable = myTextFrames[l].contents;  
        break; 
    } 

   var thisState = "~/Documents/PageNumbers/pageNumber-" + myVariable + ".ai";

   alert(thisState);

   var rect = doc.pages[i].rectangles[0];      

   try {  
       rect.place(File(thisState));  
       rect.fit (FitOptions.CONTENT_TO_FRAME);
       rect.fit (FitOptions.PROPORTIONALLY);
       rect.fit (FitOptions.CENTER_CONTENT);
   }  

   catch(e){  
       alert(e);  
   };

}
```

Comment: You need to loop through the pages. A is it, you insert the image in the same rectangle every time: `var rect = doc.rectangles[0];`, you never change `rect` afterwards, nor use `i` in the loop. Also, what is the benefit of using a function for `placePageNumber`?

Comment: I thought I was looping through the pages with the for loop. 

for (var i = 0; i < pagesLength; i++)

Apparently, I'm not

Comment: I tried 

var thisPage = app.activeWindow.activePage;

for (var i = 0; i < thisPage; i++) {

Doesn't seem to do anything...

Comment: Oh I see your point. Using that function was unnecessary.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad— I did end up seeing your point and edited the original script to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: Does it work if you force the ruler to be per-page, with `doc.viewPreferences.rulerOrigin = RulerOrigin.PAGE_ORIGIN;` at the start?